# In a web application under potentially high load, what are the use cases for class variables and methods in python?

Tags: python

I read that it isn't advisable to create static methods/variables in web applications because all the threads will have to use the same method/variable. Is there any use case for them at all in this domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Values that are supposed to be treated as constants. There's no need to have each instance initialized with the values since they'll never change.